# Active record request on jsonb column and join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, jsonb

I am trying to perform a query on a table with a jsonb field and an association with program:

```
  create_table "sessions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.jsonb "lms_data", default: "{}", null: false
    t.bigint "program_id"
```

The lms_data field has an `endDate` key, in my session model I already have a future_end_date scope :

```
  scope :future_end_date, -> { where('(lms_data::jsonb->> ?) > ?', 'endDate', Time.now) }
```

I know want to perform a query that :

- sends back all sessions with `lms_data` with `future_end_date`
- groups them by `programs.title` column
- orders them by `sessions -> lms_data -> min startDate`

I have tried :

```
 Session
        .future_end_date
        .joins(:program)
        .group('programs.title')
```

but this raises :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "lms_data" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...gram_id" WHERE "sessions"."account_id" = $2 AND ((lms_data::...
```

could you please explain why I get this error and how to perform the desired query ? (In the error message that I pasted there is  `WHERE "sessions"."account_id"` because this is a multitenant app and all queries are by default scoped on the account tenant model)

--- EDIT SCHEMA FOR BOTH MODELS ---

```
Session :
  create_table "sessions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.jsonb "lms_data", default: "{}", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "program_id"
    t.bigint "account_id"
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_sessions_on_account_id"
    t.index ["lms_data"], name: "index_sessions_on_lms_data", using: :gin
    t.index ["program_id"], name: "index_sessions_on_program_id"
  end

  create_table "programs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "headline"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "duration_in_hours"
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.boolean "featured"
    t.jsonb "lms_data", default: "{}", null: false
    t.bigint "author_id"
    t.string "dpc_number"
    t.integer "position"
    t.text "goals"
    t.string "publication_status", default: "draft"
    t.date "upcoming_date"
    t.string "session_subscription_mode", default: "sliding"
    t.integer "program_recommandation_id"
    t.bigint "account_id"
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_programs_on_account_id"
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_programs_on_author_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_programs_on_category_id"
    t.index ["lms_data"], name: "index_programs_on_lms_data", using: :gin
    t.index ["program_recommandation_id"], name: "index_programs_on_program_recommandation_id"
  end
```

Comment: Can u share the schema for both models?

Comment: @Joel_Blum yes will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `lms_data` in both tables you're using `sessions` and `programs`, so when the query is executed it doesn't know which column belongs to what table. Take this example:

```
WITH tmp(id, lms_data)  AS (values (1, NULL), (2, NULL)),
     tmp2(id, lms_data) AS (values (1, NULL))
SELECT lms_data
FROM tmp t1 INNER JOIN tmp2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
-- ERROR:  column reference "lms_data" is ambiguous
-- LINE 1: ..., tmp2(id, lms_data) as (values (1, NULL)) select lms_data f...
```

Two tables, both with the same `lms_data` column, the `JOIN` works fine, but the `SELECT` statements throws the same error you get now.

You can prefix the table name to avoid that:

```
scope :future_end_date, -> { where('(sessions.lms_data::jsonb->> ?) > ?', 'endDate', Time.now) }
```

Notice you can use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function instead of binding a constant value (`Time.now`) in the scope:

```
(sessions.lms_data::jsonb->> ?) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: I am now getting ```PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "sessions.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "sessions"."id" AS t0_r0, "sessions"."lms_data" AS t0..``` Any idea ?

Comment: That's because of the group by clause you have here `group('programs.title')`, you'll have to adapt your query depending on your needs.